# Stop Task if it's not visible

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX Task which is used to update chart:

```
public class LiveRAMPerformance
{

    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    //private Timeline timeline2;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;

        public AreaChart<Number, Number> init()
    {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        //-- Chart
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis)
        {
            // Override to remove symbols on each data point
            @Override
            protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item)
            {
            }
        };
        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

        //-- Chart Series
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().add(series);

        // look up first series fill
        Node node = sc.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-area-fill");
        // set the first series fill to translucent pale green
        node.setStyle("-fx-fill: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d4d4d4);"
            + "  -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;"
            + "  -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;");

        Node nodew = sc.lookup(".chart-series-area-line");
        // set the first series fill to translucent pale green
        nodew.setStyle("-fx-stroke: #989898; -fx-stroke-width: 1px; ");

        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        //-- Prepare Timeline
        prepareTimeline();

        return sc;
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // add a item of random data to queue
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(1150);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                //Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    //-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));
        }
        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        // update
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

When I minimize the chart or I switch the panels the Task i still running and consuming CPU resources. How I can make the Task runnable only when it's visible by the user? When I it's not visible I want to free the resources.

EDIT

Could this be the solution:

```
sc.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean, final Boolean aBoolean2)
            {
                System.out.println("####");
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the data take a long time to generate? If not, you could just use a Timeline instead of the Task. Then you can just call pause() and play() as needed.

Comment: No I just have too many charts which are not visible. I would like to save resources and disable the Threads when they are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

If the data are readily available (i.e. it doesn't take a long to to retrieve or compute), then you don't really need all the threading machinery at all. Just use a `Timeline` and a `KeyFrame` with an `EventHandler` that updates the chart. Then you can just call `pause()` on the `Timeline` when the chart is removed from the display, and `play()` when it is made visible.

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1150), 
    event -> {
        series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, Math.random()));
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
            series.getData().remove(0);
        }
    }));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Now you can get rid of the `Runnable`, `AnimationTimer`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, and `ExecutorService`.

So, for example, if your chart is in a `Tab` called `chartTab`, which is in a `TabPane` called `tabPane`, you can do

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldTab, newTab) -> {
    if (newTab == chartTab) {
        timeline.play();
    } else {
        timeline.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: I get the chart data from server so I need Task or Service. I updated the post. Can I use `.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()`? Unfortunately I don't see any string `####`. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: No, the visible property is not the same as "is it on the screen". Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty).

Comment: Is there any other solution? How I can get value "is it on the screen"?

Comment: Use a Task instead of a Runnable. Only resubmit the Task to the executor if the appropriate tab is displayed in the tab pane.

Comment: I have a case where FlowPane holds several charts. How I can determine is it visible?

Comment: If the FlowPane holds the chart, then it's visible. Not sure I understand.